# Route Parameters in Angular 2 and Express API (Get Single Post)

Tags: rest, api, angular, express, mean-stack

I'm trying to return a single article from a Express API using Angular 2.

The Express app has this section of code for single get request:

```
router.get('/articles/:articleId', (req, res) => {

  let articleId = req.params.articleId;

  Article.findById(articleId, (err, article) => {
    if(err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        res.json(article)
    }
  });

});
```

If I do console.log(article) it returns the whole JSON object in the terminal so it's working.

Next, the Article Service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {

  constructor( private http:Http ) { 
    console.log('Article service initialized...')
  }

  getArticles() {

  }

  getArticle(id) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/articles/'+id)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  addArticle(newArticle){

  }

  deleteArticle(id){
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/articles/'+id)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

With the code above the deleteArticle(id) works.

And finally, the ArticleDetailComponent looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticleService } from '../services/article.service'; 
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { ArticleComponent } from '../article/article.component'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
      selector: 'app-articledetail',
      templateUrl: './articledetail.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./articledetail.component.css']
})

export class ArticleDetailComponent implements OnInit {

      article: ArticleComponent;
      title: string;
      text: string;

      constructor( 
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute, 
        private articleService:ArticleService){   

        }

        ngOnInit() {
            var id = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
                var id = params['id'];

                this.articleService.getArticle(id)
                    .subscribe(article => {this.article = article});

                    console.log(id) //returns article id correctly
            });

        }
}
```

The articledetail.component.html looks like this:

```
    <div class="article-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
            {{article.text}}
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I run the application I can get a list of articles and delete articles by Id, but I can't get single articles to be displayed in the ArticleDetailComponent.

If I do console.log(id) within the ArticleDetailComponent it shows the article id, but I can't get the JSON object in the response and show it in the HTML.

Could somebody please tell me what's missing?

Thanks

Comment: can we see the ```articledetail.component.html``` file ? Also, if you open ```http://localhost:3000/api/articles/11``` in the browser, do you see the object?

Comment: Yes Denko, when I open http://localhost:3000/api/articles/58f3e00a35737b774a7e1958 in the browser it displays the JSON object. Thanks

Comment: did you try console.log(article) inside the ```{this.article = article}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually see where your mistake is.. you need to initialize article to empty object, because angular is probably throwing errors in the console that it cannot find `article.title`. The error is probably: cannot find title of undefined. And when angular throws an error like that the whole app freezes, and you cannot do anything. So initialize article like this:
`article: any = {}` and it will work

The other alternative would be to use the "safe operator" (?) in the template like
`{{article?.title}}`. This prevents the error, so if article is undefined it wont throw the exception, but its not a good practice rly

The third alternative would be to add *ngIf on the HTML which is throwing errors if article is undefined. Like this:

```
 <div class="article-container" *ngIf="article">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
            {{article.text}}
            <br><br>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Denko! That was the mistake, it's fixed now. Yes, the console was throwing the error: _Error in ./ArticleDetailComponent class ArticleDetailComponent - inline template:2:12 caused by: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined_ Thanks for clarifying that Denko

Comment: I am glad I could help :) You can accept the answer if it helped